# compress video files

Tags: c#, c++

i want compress video files and send it from Transmitter and receive it and decompress it and show

is sdk for it?  (for c++ or c#)

and if is possible Introduction to me some video library.

thanks.

Comment: What kind of video files?  Most popular "video files" are already compressed.  Or do you have an uncompressed stream of video frames? (If so, hatboyzero's answer below is a good starting point.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at FFMPEG and/or x264 for this.  I've also used libVLC for doing exactly this.

http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC

http://ffmpeg.org/